# A problem concerning integration in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying integration in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I get stuck in a problem about repeated integration.

Let $ \phi: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $ \psi: [c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be  integrable fuctions. Prove that $f(x,y) =\phi(x)\cdot\psi(y) $ is integrable in $A = [a,b]\times[c,d]$ and

$$ \int_Af(x,y)dxdy = \left(\int_{[a,b]}\phi(x)dx\right)\left(\int_{[c,d]}\psi(y)dy\right)$$

In my try: I got $ s(f;P) \geq s(\phi,P_1)\cdot s(\psi,P_2)$ where $P=P_1 \times P_2$ is a partition for $A$.
And $ S(f;P) \leq S(\phi,P_1)\cdot S(\psi,P_2)$ but I can't conclude nothing from here.

My problem is related to: [Proving $\int_A f(x,y)\ dxdy = \left(\int_a^b \phi(x)\ dx\right)\left(\int_c^d \psi(y)\ dy\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464358/proving-int-a-fx-y-dxdy-left-int-ab-phix-dx-right-left-int-cd)

But I didn't understand that discussion.

Thank you

Comment: You are doing Riemann integration I presume?

Comment: Do you know Fubini's theorem for the Riemann integral?

Comment: I know the "Fubini's theorem" (Repeated Integration Theorem). My trouble is show that $f$ is integrable. I made a new try, $f$ is integrable because the set $D_f$ where $f$ is not continuous is a subset of union where $\phi$ and  $\psi$ is not continuous then $D_f$ has null measure.